# VScode replace regex before and after a match

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

I am trying to do a search and replace for a certain string.

Let's say:

```
this.$store.getters.xyz
```

And make it:

```
this.$store.getters['xyz']
```

One problem is that the string could end in either a space, a semicolon or a newline character.

To me it seems I have to have an empty group at the end to replace.

My current attempt:

```
(getters\.)((?<=getters.)[A-z]*$)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

**Find What**:      `\b(this\.\$store\.getters)\.(\w+)`
Or,                   `\b(this\.\$store\.getters)\.(\w+)(?=[\s;]|$)`
**Replace with**: `$1['$2']`

[image]

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(this\.\$store\.getters)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `this.$store.getters` string
- `\.`  - a dot
- `(\w+)` - Group 2 (`$2`): one or more letters, digits or `_`
- `(?=[\s;]|$)` - the next char must be a whitespace (`\s`), `;` or end of a line (`$`).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```js
function replaceGetter(str) {
    return str.replace(/getters\.\w+/igm, function (str) {
        return "getters['" + str.substr('getters.'.length, str.length) + "']";
    });
}
//TEST
var input = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
var output = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
function update() {
    output.innerHTML = replaceGetter(input.value);
}
input.addEventListener('change', update);
input.addEventListener('keyup', update);
```

Answer (score 1):

Find:

```
this\.\$store\.getters\.([^\s;]+)(.*)$
```

Replace:

```
this.$store.getters['$1']$2
```

Example:

[image]